# Add < value> line in multiple xml files at once

Tags: python, xml

I am interested in modifying multiple xml files at once using Python, as it follows:

My xml files look like this:

```
<FirstName>John</Firstname>
<ID>9999</ID>
<Phone>No</Phone>

<FirstName>Andrew</Firstname>
<ID>3012</ID>
<Phone>No</Phone>

<FirstName>Brian</Firstname>
<ID>9999</ID>
<Phone>No</Phone>
```

For each line that has < ID> equals to 9999, I want to add another line right after < Phone> with the value '< Notes>Random Note< /Notes>'. But only for the ones that have the < ID> equals to 9999. Therefore, after running the script, I want something like this:

```
<FirstName>John</Firstname>
<ID>9999</ID>
<Phone>No</Phone>
<Notes>Random Note</Notes>

<FirstName>Andrew</Firstname>
<ID>3012</ID>
<Phone>No</Phone>

<FirstName>Brian</Firstname>
<ID>9999</ID>
<Phone>No</Phone>
<Notes>Random Note</Notes>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You'll likely want to look into using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this. Essentially, you can find each tag block, verify that e.g. `<ID>` equals ex. `9999` and append the proper tag (e.g. `<Notes> Random Note </Notes>`).

Comment: Unfortunately programming questions are off-topic here but are accepted on our sister site [so]. However, I believe this would be closed there as well as it does not demonstrate any research or code the OP has tried.